# Only import specific data columns - Comma Delimited List

Tags: sql, asp.net, database

I used the following command to import data from a text file, however, I need to find out a way of selecting specific columns within the text file. The following links have been suggested to me however I'm struggling to understand whether I need to replace my current SQL with the examples on MSDN:

```
BULK INSERT T2 FROM 'c:\Temp\Data.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187908.aspx

I have the following fields held within a text file which is separated by comma. The data is also separated by comma enabling me to use the above code to import it all.

**Date,Time,Order,Item,Delivery Slot,Delivery Time**

Is there a way to only import Date, Time, Item and Delivery Time into an SQL database table?

Comment: I'm sure there are many ways of doing it and more knowledgable people than me will be able to help more, but you could write a script in many different languages to accomplish that task. What language / technology is your target for accomplishing this task? MySQL? MSSQL? A bash language?

Comment: @Will Buck Im creating a project in ASP.Net with C# and SQL which is built it. All the data currently comes from text files. I like using batch files however i know they arnt the best of things. So, this where i decided it might be bet to use SQL.

Comment: Why not just bulk insert into temporary T3 then select from T3 the columns you want into T2?  Manipulating data once you have it in a table IMO would be easier; just throw away the temp table when your done.  Yes, its some overhead but far faster than having to parce out the column.  Or have the system generating the CSV not put Delivery Slot in the output, or open the output in excel delete the column and resave as CSV... lots of options here.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Format File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx) for your `BULK INSERT`.  You can specify which fields are imported through this file definition.

**EDIT**: example from MSDN.

```
BULK INSERT bulktest..t_float
FROM 'C:\t_float-c.dat' WITH (FORMATFILE='C:\t_floatformat-c-xml.xml');
GO
```

Comment: Thats what the links tell me to do but where do i put it, in an SQL statement?